# Ant Validate SQLPlus

Tags: oracle, ant

I am running an Ant task that will do an oracle request

```
SELECT sysdate FROM dual
```

and I would like to verify this statement is successful. What would be the best way to validate this in ANT? I have found two options that might work.

1. Set the response to a property and validate with regular expressions (or something else).
2. Wrap the statement inside a trycatch block.

Thanks for you help...

EDIT

I'm using a SQL Task, what I have so far looks like:

```
<project>
<echo message="Executing SQL..."/>
<target name="main">
    <trycatch>
        <try>
            <sql ...
            print="true"
            >
                SELECT sysdate FROM dual;
            </sql>
        </try>
        <catch>
            <echo message="Error" />
        </catch>
    </trycatch>
</target>
<echo message="Done executing SQL."/>
</project>
```

I execute this from a shell script, but it is not running the target stuff...

Comment: What is the task you are using?  There are some SQL tasks for ant, or you could run sqlplus via a shell.  Or are you calling some Java code?